# How to update records in table based on group by on multiple fields and select first record from each group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a tables like below :

**TargetDatabaseInfo:**

```
TargetDatabaseId   TargetDatabaseName     ServerInfo
1                   SchoolDb               abc.123
2                   MyEmployee             pqr.123
```

**ManagementRulesInfo:**

```
ManagementRuleId    IsApplicable    TargetDatabaseId     BaseRuleId
11                    1               1                  101
12                    1               2                  101
```

**ProcessSchedularInfo:**

```
ProcessId      ProcessName    ExecuteOn     Status       ManagementRuleId
1               P1            2022-09-23    Pending       11
2               P2            2022-09-24    Pending       11
3               P3            2022-09-25    Pending       11
4               P1            2022-09-25    Pending       12
```

Now, I want to update the status of only those process to "Start" whose status is "Pending" if there is no other "Pending" process against that "TargetDatabaseId" and BaseRuleId". So "TargetDatabaseId" and BaseRuleId" columns will be together to identify a "TargetDatabase" to run the process against. Process whose status needs to update will be from "Old" to "New" and only 1 process status will be updated against "TargetDatabaseId" and "BaseRuleId".

Final output in the `ProcessSchedularInfo` table will be:

**ProcessSchedularInfo:**

```
ProcessId      ProcessName    ExecuteOn     Status       ManagementRuleId
1               P1            2022-09-23    Start         11
2               P2            2022-09-24    Pending       11
3               P3            2022-09-25    Pending       11
4               P1            2022-09-25    Start         12
```

My query:

```
UPDATE p    
  SET Status = 'Start'   
  from ProcessSchedularInfo p
  INNER JOIN ManagementRulesInfo m
    ON p.ManagementRuleId = m.ManagementRuleId
     group by m.TargetDatabaseId,m.BaseRuleId
```

But here I am not getting like how do I select every first Process for `ManagementRuleId` ("TargetDatabaseId" and "BaseRuleId")?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `group by` statement within the `update` command as when doing a `group by` you will lose the ID of that row. To get that functionality you have to wrap the `group by` in a subquery. Now there is probably a more elegant solution to this, but here is what I came up with that works to your desired output in the question.

```
UPDATE ProcessSchedularInfo
SET Status = 'Start'
WHERE ProcessId IN(SELECT ProcessId
                   FROM ProcessSchedularInfo psi
                   JOIN ManagementRulesInfo mri on mri.ManagementRuleId = psi.ManagementRuleId
                   JOIN (SELECT MIN(executeOn) as 'ExecuteOn',
                                mri.TargetDatabaseId
                         FROM ProcessSchedularInfo psi
                         JOIN ManagementRulesInfo mri on mri.ManagementRuleId = psi.ManagementRuleId
                         GROUP BY mri.TargetDatabaseId,
                                  mri.BaseRuleId) tb ON tb.ExecuteOn = psi.ExecuteOn AND
                                                        tb.TargetDatabaseId = mri.TargetDatabaseId);
```

I used the `group by` to identify the earliest `executeOn`s per `TargetDatabaseId` and `BaseRuleId` then joined that back to an ungrouped result set to get the `ProcessId`s and update those records. You can [see it working here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9ed3ef/8)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working because I am getting multiple process from the same ManagementRuleId. For eg ManagementRuleId = 11

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow the only way this wouldn't work is if there was multiple records with the same ExecuteOn and ManagementRuleId, if that is the case we will need another field that can uniquely identify the records